# Strange tips when opening the git bash

Tags: git-bash

When i open the git bash from the explorer-context-menu most recently a strange tip-box appears, when I run a normal CMD this tip does not appear.

Any idea what it is?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is part of the Xbox App in Windows 10, for taking screenshots or recordings of games.

To disable it for that window:

1. Open the program you wish to disassociate with the Windows Game Bar and make sure it's the activated foreground window
2. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. Press the `Settings` button:

[image]

4. Uncheck `Remember this as a game`

[image]

This should stop the bar from displaying.